# SignalR HubContext Clients is null after running Unit test on it with Mock client proxy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, signalr, xunit, signalr-hub

I have the following 2 files, one, which is a `HubController` class and the other, which is a Unit test class.

`HubController.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalR.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HubController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<HothHub> _hubContext;

        public HubController(IHubContext<HothHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        [HttpPost("{id}")]  // POST /api/values/xyz
        public async Task PostAsync(string id)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("update Post()");

            // Make a call to the client based on the connection ID and call client method
            await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("hubToClientUpdate");

            //return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

`Tests.cs`:

```
using Xunit;
using Moq;
using System.Dynamic;
using SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SignalR.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System;

namespace TestSignalR
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async Task HubsAreMockableViaDynamic()
        {
            bool sendCalled = false;
            var mockClients = new Mock<IHubCallerConnectionContext<dynamic>>();
            // The IHubCallerConnectionContext interface is the proxy object with, which you invoke methods on the client
            dynamic all = new ExpandoObject();
            // This is the client proxy object where we define the method, which we will invoke on the client
            all.SendAsync = new Action<string>((method) =>
            {
                sendCalled = true;
            });
            // Define the function that will be called on the client when HubController calls its PostAsync method
            // The test engine will call the PostAsync method in HubController, which in turn calls this method postAsync here
            mockClients.Setup(m => m.All).Returns((ExpandoObject)all);
            // Setting up the mock client so when the All property is called we return an instance of the Client proxy, which in this case
            // is the dynamic object all
            var hubContext = new Mock<IHubContext<MyHub>>();
            // Created a mock of the IHubContext object required by the HubController class
            hubContext.Setup(x => x.Clients).Returns(mockClients.Object as IHubClients);
            // Set up the mock of the IHubContext object so that when the Clients property is called, then the instance of the mock client
            // object is returned
            HubController hubController = new HubController(hubContext.Object);
            // Created an instance of the HubController class, which is needed to call the PostAsync function in it
            await hubController.PostAsync("id");
            Assert.True(sendCalled);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a `MyHub.cs` file, which derives from the `Hub` class but this class doesn't contain anything useful for my test.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalR
{
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public string GetConnectionId() => Context.ConnectionId;
    }
}
```

Now the issue I'm having is that when I either run a test on HubsAreMockableViaDynamic() or run a debug on it, it will return me the following error,
[image: hubContext Clients is null]

This test has come about after following the documentation from Microsoft here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-signalr-applications. Now I suspect the problem is with this line here, `hubContext.Setup(x => x.Clients).Returns(mockClients.Object as IHubClients);` in Tests.cs, which is causing the problem. Without the cast there is the following,

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubClients' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubClients'   TestSignalR C:\Sourcesafe\2023\Integration\WebhookBot\WebhookBot\TestSignalR\Tests.cs   38  Active

I'm quite new to `SignalR` and `Mock` objects so I'm stuck as to why this isn't working after following the documentation from Microsoft. Is there anyone who could shed some light into why this issue is happening and how to resolve it please?
Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using dynamic and expandoObjects everywhere? Why not just use the actual type of HothHub?

Comment: Just following the example set in the Microsoft documentation (referenced in the post). Using the actual types does work but I'd like to get it working by using these "generic" types instead.